# open all ports to specific IP with firewalld

Tags: firewalld

I'm on a red hat 7 machine, and I need to open all ports to a specific IP on the firewall.

I tried this command:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule='   rule family="ipv4"   source address="64.39.96.0/20"   port protocol="tcp" port="*" accept'
```

But I'm getting an invalid port error for the *

Does anyone know and can tell me how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use a firewalld *zone* for this. Zones can be specified either by interface or by source IP address.

In fact, by default, a zone which accepts all traffic already exists, and it is named `trusted`. By default, though, nothing is in this zone. So, you don't even need to create a zone, just add the IP address to the `trusted` zone.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-source=64.39.96.0/20
```

In addition to CIDR ranges, you can specify single IP addresses or ipset names prefixed with `ipset:`.

After this, all traffic from the specified addresses will be allowed on any port. Remember to [make it permanent](https://serverfault.com/a/674887/126632), either by repeating the command with `--permanent` appended, or by running `firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent`.

Comment: I also used `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32` to restrict to just my own Public IP address.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the port can either be a single port number `123` or a port range `123-456` and `*` is not a valid input.

**Not** specifying any specific port number/range will match **any** port.